# $query->with() is working but $query->load() not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have three models.

1. Section
2. Subject
3. Chapter

Section has many subjects and subject has many chapters.
I want to load a section with all its subjects and the subjects with all its chapters.
Here is the code I am trying:

```
$section = Section::find(1)->load(['subjects' => function ($query) {
                    $query->load('chapters');
                }]);
```

This is not working. `$query->load('chapters')` this part gives me error. But if I try this code:

```
$section = Section::find(1)->load(['subjects' => function ($query) {
                $query->with('chapters');
            }]);
```

This is working. I have some issues with `$query->with()` so I want to use `$query->load()` instead. What should I do to use `load()` instead of `with()`>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent Query builder does not have a function called `load()`. But Eloquent Model does.

```php
$section = Section::find(1)
               ->load(['subjects' => function ($query) { // in here you are calling load on a model (Section).
                    $query->load('chapters'); // in here you are calling load on a query builder instance.
               }]);
```

- when you want to load some relations after fetching a model, use `load()` function
- when you want to load some relations while fetching models, use `with()` function

in your case you have already fetched the subject. So you can use `load('subject')`. But while you are loading subjects (you have not fetched the subjects yet), so you should call `with('chapters')`

**EDIT**
short version of your second approach

```php
$section = Section::find(1)->load(['subjects.chapters');
```

If there is no special requirements to fetch the section alone, the better approach is load both subjects and chapters while fetching the section.

```php
$section = Section::with('subjects.chapters')->find(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

why not using:

```
$section = Section::query()->with('subjects.chapters')->find(1)
```

This will preload subjects with chapters and get you a fast result.